# How many ternary strings with at most $k$ ones and $k$ minus ones

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider for $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k \leq n$  the following set
$$
S_{k,n} := \{z \in \{-1,0,1\}^n : \#\{i:z_i = 1\} \leq k~\text{and}~\#\{i:z_i = -1\}\leq k\}.
$$

I want to determine the cardinality of $S$. I know that there are ${n \choose k} 2^{n-k}$ number of strings with exactly $k$ ones and likewise ${n \choose k} 2^{n-k}$ number of strings with exactly $k$ minus ones. But I have to remove the strings where we have for example $k$ one's and more than $k$ minus ones. I think I have to use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion. I'm REALLY stuck on this problem. Hope someone can help me.

Example: let $n=3$ and $k=1$. Then we have
$$
S_{3,1} = \{(0,0,0), (1,-1,0),(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1),(-1,1,0),(-1,0,1), (0,-1,1),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,-1),(0,-1,0),(-1,0,0)\}
$$
and so we have $\#S_{3,1} = 13$.

Comment: So where are you stuck with the PIE principle. Also, have you consider a recursion? Or have you consider also to fix the number of $1$,$-1$ to exactly $a,b\leq k$ and count those?

Comment: It is easy to write the answer as a summation:
$$
|S_{k,n}|=\sum_{i=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{n!}{i!\cdot j!\cdot (n-i-j)!}
$$
Would this form be acceptable to you? If not, you should edit to clarify. I expect that there is no "closed" form for $|S_{k,n}|$. If you have reason to believe otherwise, you should also include that context in your post.

Comment: @MikeEarnest. It would be nice, if you can give a proof of the formula. Maybe you can give it as an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: @wayne But the formula is its own proof. The number of strings with $i$ copies of $+1$, with $j$ copies of $-1$, and with $n-i-j$ copies of $0$, is $\frac{n!}{i!j!(n-i-j)!}$ (imagine first all symbols are distinct, permute in $n!$ ways, then divide by $i!$ since all $+1$'s are identical, etc). Then sum over all valid $i$ $j$.

Comment: If you want, you can now write an answer yourself, then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a sequence of length $n$ in which the number of $1$ is $i$ and the number of $-1$ is $j$, you can choose among $\binom{n}{i}$ possibilities for the positions of the $1$'s. Next in the remaining $n-i$ slots, you have $\binom{n-i}{j}$ possibilities to choose the positions of the $-1$. The remaining $n-i-j$ slots will be filled with $0$'s. This gives
$$
\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{j} = \frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!} \frac{(n-i)!}{j!(n-i-j)!} = \frac{n!}{i!j!(n-i-j)!}
$$
It remains to sum these values to get
$$
S_{k,n} =\sum_{0 \leqslant i,j \leqslant k} \frac{n!}{i!j!(n-i-j)!}
$$